Can Google Nest Door Bell API integration have two way audio communication
I am trying to integrate Google Doorbell (battery) API integration using flutter.
I could receive the video stream and audio stream to the app. But I could not receive the audio stream to the doorbell.
I could see the offer is a=recvonly (receive only)..
So does that mean we cannot send the audio stream from mobile device's microphone to doorbell?
from docs
I tried different approaches including enabling the track.But none did not helped me
 localStream.getAudioTracks().forEach((track) {
 try {
      track.enabled = true;
      _peerConnection!.addTrack(track, localStream);
     } catch (e) {
       utils.error("Error adding track: $e");
     }
 });

